# How do I make use of only Date under Struct(Date/Time) to get date from .csv file in unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-blueprint

How do I make use of only Date under Struct(Date/Time) to get date from .csv file in unreal engine?

I am using Event graph and so I am not coding.

Comment: I get date if I use date variables pin type as 'String'. But I don't want to use string.

Comment: better you write this comment into the question section under the label approach i used.